# 親ViewのViewModel⇔子ViewのBinding方法について

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

下記クラス図の通り、MainWindowView ⇔ MainWindowViewModel、DialogView ⇔ DialogViewModelはDataContext、DataTempleteで紐づいています。
また、NavigationServiceを使用してDialogViewのFrameのPageを切り替えています。

Pageの部品とDialogViewModelのプロパティをBindingで紐づけたいのですが方法が分かりません。
※NavigationServiseを使用してPage切替をしているため、Pageを動的に生成しています。

DialogViewでPageのインスタンス生成時に、PageのDataContextにDialogViewのDataContextを設定すれば、実現できるのは確認できました。できれば、Xaml上で同等の記述をしたいです。

---

**クラス図**
[image: クラス図]

**ソースコード**

・ MainWindowView

```
<Window x:Class="Apps.RelativeTestApp.App.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Apps.RelativeTestApp.App"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Apps.RelativeTestApp.App"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    local:DialogAttachedBehavior.WindowViewModel="{Binding DialogViewModel}">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DialogViewModel}">
            <local:DialogView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="open" Command="{Binding OpenDialogCommand}" Margin="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

・DialogView

```
<UserControl x:Class="Apps.RelativeTestApp.App.DialogView"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Apps.RelativeTestApp.App"
     xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Apps.RelativeTestApp.App"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="90*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="TitleLabel" Content="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Frame x:Name="PageFrame" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621424/page-datacontext-not-inherited-from-parent-frame に同様の質問を見つけました。

`Page`は`Frame`とは独立して動作しているようで、DataContextは継承されません。
質問文にあるようにコードビハインドでの実装が正解かと思いますが、どうしてもXAMLのみで解決したい場合は以下のようにControlTemplateを定義することで`Page`が`Frame`のDataContextを参照するようになります。

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Frame}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Frame}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_FrameCP" DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="NavigationUIVisibility" Value="Visible">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource FrameNavChromeTemplateKey}" />
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="JournalOwnership" Value="OwnsJournal" />
                    <Condition Property="NavigationUIVisibility" Value="Automatic" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource FrameNavChromeTemplateKey}" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: 確かにStyleタグで修飾しておけば、FrameのDataContextを参照できることを確認できました。ありがとうございました。